# How can i use setState inside initState?

Tags: flutter, dart

I get some data from an API and i want to use it in a DropdownButton. When i change the value of the DropdownButton its doesn't change on the screen.

I think it's because i use setState into an initState, but i must put the FutureBuilder into the initState to avoid loading data many times.
How can i fix this?

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
String _selItem;
FutureBuilder _FBDDB;

void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _FBDDB = FutureBuilder(
    future: getdata(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return DropdownButton<String>(
          value: _selItem,
          onChanged: (v) {
            setState(() {
              _selItem = v;
            });
          },
          items: snapshot.data.items.map((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: item.id, child: Text(item.name));
          }).toList(),
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        alertErr(context, snapshot.error.toString());
      }
      return Container(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
    },
  );
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Container(child: _FBDDB,),
  ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing it right way, check out this code.

```
@override
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
String _selItem;
FutureBuilder _FBDDB;
Future _future; // create this

void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // assign it here
  _future = getData();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future, // use it here
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                value: _selItem,
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selItem = v;
                  });
                },
                items: snapshot.data.items.map((item) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: item.id, child: Text(item.name));
                }).toList(),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              alertErr(context, snapshot.error.toString());
            }
            return Container(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the entire code inside the initState(). You need not do that. Just place the variable whose value you need to set when changed, and all other code outside the initState().